# What is the technique to dynamically build out collapsible data sets in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, listview, jquery-mobile

I can only assume that what I am trying to do is a very common requirement when working with dynamic javascript applications.

For this particular example, I want to request detailed test results via JSON. So for some users they might have done 20 tests, others might have done 1. Some users might have got 2 questions wrong in a particular test which will get referenced, others might have got 10 questions wrong, some got 0. Only the questions that are wrong would get displayed.

So in other words I am requesting a different layout for a collapsible data set upon each user who requests it.

**The static code might look something like this:**

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h2>Test Number 2 - 2 out of 5 correct</h2>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="d">
            <li data-role="list-divider">You did not complete the following:</li>
            <li><h3>A (answer is: X)</h3></li>
            <li><h3>B (answer is: Y)</h3></li>
            <li><h3>C (answer is: Z)</h3></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h2>Test Number 1 - 4 out of 5 correct</h2>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="d">
            <li data-role="list-divider">You did not complete the following:</li>
            <li><h3>A (answer is: X)</h3></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

As somebody who is relatively new to JavaScript and jQuery I am still getting the hang of this, I have played around with some DOM manipulation in the past. Just wondered if there is another name for what I am trying to accomplish, and maybe even a library, pre-built code that I can use floating around GitHub, etc that does something like this without me having to build everything from scratch. Want to do this the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a special framework for this, everything you need is already a part of jQuery.

I have created an example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/HBxTs/

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d">
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h2>Simple list</h2>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="movie-data" data-theme="a">

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS :**

```
$('#index').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){ 
    $.ajax({url: "http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/json/23afca60ebf72f8d88cdcae2c4f31866/The Goonies",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: 'successCallback',
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true);
        },
        complete: function() {
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        },
        success: function (result) {
            ajax.parseJSONP(result);
        },
        error: function (request,error) {
            alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
        }
    });         
});


var ajax = {  
    parseJSONP:function(result){
        //var jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON(parameters);
        $('#movie-data').append('<li>Movie name:<span> ' + result[0].original_name+ '</span></li>');
        $('#movie-data').append('<li>Popularity:<span> ' + result[0].popularity + '</span></li>');
        $('#movie-data').append('<li>Rating:<span> ' + result[0].rating+ '</span></li>');
        $('#movie-data').append('<li>Overview:<span> ' + result[0].overview+ '</span></li>');
        $('#movie-data').append('<li>Released:<span> ' + result[0].released+ '</span></li>');  
        $('#movie-data').listview('refresh');        
    }
}
```

Only thing you need to take care is to execute this function after content has been added:

```
$('#movie-data').listview('refresh');
```

It is used for listview restyling.

Comment: Thanks @gajotres, I adjusted for my needs, but it doesn't work. Do you know where I am going wrong?
HTML:
<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d" id="movie-data">
</div>
JS:
$('#movie-data').append('<div data-role="collapsible" id="collapsible1"></div>');
$('#movie-data').listview('refresh');    
$('#collapsible1').append('<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="movie-listview" data-theme="a">');
$('#collapsible1').listview('refresh');    
$('#movie-listview').append('<li>Rating:<span>Hello</span></li>');
$('#movie-listview').listview('refresh');

Comment: Use .listview('refresh'); only and only after all content has been appended. But as I can see you are dynamically adding more then listview content. In that case you need to trigger $('#index').trigger('pagecreate'); where #index is a page id. So trigger that function on your page. .trigger('pagecreate'); should also be triggered only after all content has been appended.

Comment: If you still can make it work I will create you another example.

Comment: would really appreciate it, this is still very abstract for me!

Comment: .listview('refresh') is used only to refresh/restyle a listview while .trigger('pagecreate') will restyle whole content.